# With Navigation.push (v2 of react native navigation from wix) I am not getting props in destination component. How do I access props?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am passing props using Navigation.push then trying to get the props as seen below in destination component.

**Result of attempt:** I get 'image of undefined'

I am using redux in my react-native-app and redux is working correctly and I can see my data in other components. But when I do push and try to access the props in destination component I am seeing nothing.

All I get is componentId and rootTag in placeDetail component when I just console.log the props. What am I doing wrong?

```js
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: "navigation.playground.PlaceDetailScreen"
  },
  options: {
    topBar: {
      title: {
        text: selPlace.name
      }
    }
  },
  passProps: {
    selectedPlace: selPlace
  }
});
```

```js
const placeDetail = props => {
   
   console.log(props)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Image source={props.navigationselectedPlace.image} style={styles.placeImage} />
        <Text style={styles.placeName}>{props.selectedPlace.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onItemDeleted}>
          <View style={styles.deleteButton}>
            <Icon size={30} name="ios-trash" color="red" />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your Navigation.push everything should be inside the component object.

like so:

You currently have the options and pass props outside of the component.

```js
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: 'example.PushedScreen',
    passProps: {
      text: 'Pushed screen'
    },
    options: {
      topBar: {
        title: {
          text: 'Pushed screen title'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```